# Unable to install HPLIP for HP P1007 printer in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hp, hplip

I am trying to install HPLIP in Ubuntu 20.04 release for HP P1007 Printer. but i am getting the following error when installing the HPLIP

```
DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python3-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes gtk2-engines-pixbuf'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
**error: A required dependency 'python3-pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.**


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


**RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'python3-pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.**
```

When i tried to install the Required dependencies python3-pyqt5 its already exists in my system, please find below message when trying to install missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
[sudo] password for mahan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Please help me resolving regarding this issue.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: It might help if you cleaned up your post; ie. you mention Ubuntu 12.04 LTS clearly in the title but only mention 20.04 (on on-topic release) later on. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled the Ubuntu 20.04 version again and installed the puthon3-qt5 in Ubuntu and then i can able to install hp-plugin, this time i never found any issues and printer is also working fine.

Those who are facing the issue in installing please follow the below steps

1) sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 (no need to download and install HP-Lip in ubuntu 20.04 since this version has already hplip installed to verify run dpkg -l hplip)
2) run hp-plugin, it will opens up the HP Plugin GUI